# JavaScript Math.random() returns "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, random

I have a block of code that uses Math.random(). I noticed that occasionally the return value would be "Undefined". This is the code I used:

```
return data.map(val => {
    var r = Math.random();
    if (r < this.mutChance) {
        console.log(Math.random);
        debugger;
        return this.rDna(val);
    }
    return val;
});
```

When i set the mutChance variable to 0 and let the code run for a bit eventually debugger gets called and shows the value of r to be undefined. I tried to reproduce the problem by running in console

```
var test = Math.random();
while(test){
    test = Math.random();
}
```

However, this loop never ended. I have no idea why the function would act differently within my object, and the console.log(Math.random); Says that the function still has its native code. Nowhere do I override the random function, nor do I use the variable r anywhere else.

I am relatively new to JavaScript and couldn't find this problem anywhere else. The only other code I have imported is the p5.min.js package.

Comment: As he mentions, he logs the function (instead of its value) to ensure that it hasn't been overridden.

Comment: @Pointy Smallhack is right, the console.log is just to confirm nothing in my code is modifying the original function, not to try to get an actual value from it.

Comment: `Math.random()` returning `undefined` would be a platform problem; it seems *extremely* unlikely that that's actually happening. Much more likely is some weird bad behavior in the debugger. An explicit test for `typeof r` being `"number"` or simply `r !== undefined` would be more trustworthy.

Comment: I think the problem is with how chrome dev tools was displaying the value. When I run `console.log(r);` instead it no longer displays as undefined, but instead as some very small number. It also turns out a different part of my code was changing the value of "mutChance" from 0 to a different, also very small value. I have no idea why chrome would interpret these numbers as "undefined".

Comment: What does `this.rDna(val)` return?

Comment: @Thomas It's unrelated to the problem, however its an array (length 5) of random 0's or 1's

Comment: And never `undefined`!? because that would have been to me the most likely place to produce this `undefined` value

Comment: @Thomas Yea, the problem was with how chrome dev tools was displaying the values. Once I added `console.log(r)` chrome started showing me the actual values. For some reason when the number was low enough without the console.log it would just display as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with how chrome was interpreting the very small values

[Without console.log chrome shows it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79hvS.png)

[With console.log chrome displays correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlmvX.png)